# XML-Schema type regex or pattern for regex

Tags: xml, regex, xsd, schema, regular-language

I want to validate if a certain attribute is a valid regex. Is there some direct built in type in xml schema maybe `xs:regex`?

Otherwise is there a regex that defines valid regexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, by definition, no regex that can validate regular expressions.

Regular expressions can *match* regular languages, they are not *themselves* a regular language. Much like there can be no regular expression to validate HTML or JavaScript.

To find out if a string is a legal regular expression, it's easiest to try and create a regex object from it. In XSD itself this is impossible, so you'd need the help of an external tool.